# Strange message after wiping data/factory resetting on Pixel 6 device

Tags: security, rom-flashing, bootloader, google-pixel-6, android-13

Last night, I flashed my Pixel 6 phone because I want to move to Pixel 7. After flashing, I turned on the phone for a while, and then I used the Recovery >Wipe data/factory reset option. Unfortunately, after finishing, a strange message appeared.

```
-- Wiping data --
E: Open failed: /metadata/ota: No such file or directory
Formatting /data...
Formatting /metadata...
Wiping Titan M...
Wiping keys...
E:gto_esehal SecureElement:t1_recv_window_append free = 261

E:gto_esehal SecureElement:t1_recv_window_append free = 261

E:gto_esehal SecureElement:t1_recv_window_append free = 261

E:gto_esehal SecureElement:t1_recv_window_append free = 261

Data wipe complete
```

Is it something serious? Can I sell the phone in this condition or should I return it for a warranty? Isn't this some sort of security flaw? Other than that, everything works fine.

Comment: Which part of the posted message do you think is strange? Titan is the Google security chip.

Comment: On a tangent - I hope you signed out of your Google account before factory reset, else there would be [factory-reset-protection](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset-protection/info) kicking in//On the main question, besides what @Robert said, there is no error reported, so it's fine AFAIK